# How can i know whether the LUKS is using passphrase or key file for authentication purpose?

Tags: server, kernel, encryption, lvm, ecryptfs

Lets an example, i have a Linux partition /dev/sda6 and already encryption been enabled with DM-crypt (cryptsetup) tool.

As i know dm-crypt can have two way of authentication like with key file or passphrase which we can specify at the time of enabling of encryption. But is there any way so that i can identify the encryption enabled happened with key file or passphrase from its LUKS header or any other possible option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LUKS doesn't really make any difference between keys and passphrases; so a passphrase is a key you type in, if you like. Just by looking at the LUKS metadata, it's not possible to tell whether a key or passphrase was used. However, if there is an unencrypted `/boot` and Initramfs, you can usually tell from the scripts present there, whether it would be asking the user for a passphrase or look for a keyfile somewhere. In particular, you may want to check `/etc/crypttab` as that's the most common configuration file for determining which method is used to decrypt something at boot time. If your root partition is part of the encryption, the only way to get at that file is again to unpack the Initramfs of the system's kernel using `cpio`.

Comment: Thanks frostschutz! is there any way to find the encryption percentage(%) in progress? What i know, it gives only the status like active or inactive with the command cryptsetup status <device>. Any thought..?

Comment: There is no progress. It's either encrypted, or it isn't.

Comment: okay... thanks frostschutz! Currently what i know that dm crypt is destructive in nature that means if we enable the encryption on a partition all the data would get deleted. But is there any way so that we can keep the existing data as it is.. with encryption enable.